# Is memcopy extra data from std::string to std::array<char,size> an undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, memcpy

I don't mean to use this code in production environment, but I'm a little confuse about it.I thought it must be undefined,however,I ran this code without crash.Is this just conincidence?

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <string>

auto main(int argc, char** argv) -> int {
  // for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
  std::array<char, 1000> dst;
  std::string src = "hello world";
  memcpy(dst.data(), src.c_str(), dst.size()); // is this undefined behavior?
  // }
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior does not mean "guaranteed crash"

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica So I asked `Is this just conincidence?`

Comment: It is undefined behaviour, and undefined behaviour can mean a failure to crash. I'm not sure I'd describe that situation as a coincidence though. It just regular undefined behaviour.

Comment: fyi Undefined Behaviour can cause Time Travel 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527401/undefined-behavior-causing-time-travel

Comment: _Is it just coincidence?_ This question is generally unanswerable. It may be a coincidence, it may not. One would need to study the generated assembly, at least. At the assembly level, it's possible that nothing illegal happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought it must be undefined

Yes, it is undefined behaviour. `src.data` points to an array of 12 chars (=12 bytes), but `memcpy` will attempt to read 1000 bytes from it, so it reads out of bounds.

> however, I ran this code without crash

That's the point of undefined behaviour. Anything might happen. This includes running without any problems at all.