# What is uninitialized memory and why isn't it initialized when allocating?

Tags: rust, memory-management, allocation

Taking this signature for a method of the `GlobalAllocator`:

```
unsafe fn alloc(&self, layout: Layout) -> *mut u8
```

and this sentence from the method's documentation:

- *The allocated block of memory may or may not be initialized.*

Suppose that we are going to allocate some chunk of memory for an `[i32, 10]`. Assuming the size of `i32` it's 4 bytes, our example array would need 40 bytes for the requested storage.

Now, the allocator found a memory spot that fits our requirements. Some 40 bytes of a memory region... but... what's there? I always read the term *garbage data*, and assume that it's just old data already stored there by another process, program... etc.

- What's unitialized memory? Just data that is not initialized with zeros of with some default value for the type that we want to store there?
- Why not always memory it's initialized before returning the pointer? It's too costly? But the memory must be initialized in order to use it properly and not cause `UB`. Why then doesn't comes already initialized?
- When some resource it's *deallocated*, things musn't be pointing to that freed memory. That's that place got zeroed? What really happens when you `deallocate` some piece of memory?

Comment: Due to the way virtual memory works in modern OSes, it might be memory that _doesn't even exist_ until you try to write to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's unitialized memory? Just data that is not initialized with zeros of with some default value for the type that we want to store there?

It's worse than either of those. Reading from uninitialized memory is undefined behavior, as in you can no longer reason about a program which does so. Practically, compilers often optimize assuming that code paths that would trigger undefined behavior are never executed and their code can be removed. Or not, depending on how aggressive the compiler is.

If you could reliably read from the pointer, it would contain arbitrary data. It may be zeroes, it may be old data structures, it may be parts of old data structures. It may even be things like passwords and encryption keys, which is another reason why reading uninitialized memory is problematic.

> Why not always memory it's initialized before returning the pointer? It's too costly? But the memory must be initialized in order to use it properly and not cause UB. Why then doesn't comes already initialized?

Yes, cost is the issue. The first thing that is typically done after allocating a piece of memory is to write to it. Having the allocator "pre-initialize" the memory is wasteful when the caller is going to overwrite it anyway with the values it wants. This is especially significant with large buffers used for IO or other large storage.

> When some resource it's deallocated, things musn't be pointing to that freed memory. That's that place got zeroed? What really happens when you deallocate some piece of memory?

It's up to how the memory allocator is implemented. Most don't waste processing power to clear the data that's been deallocated, since it will be overwritten anyway when it's reallocated. Some allocators may write some bookkeeping data to the freed space. `GlobalAllocator` is an interface to whatever allocator the system comes with, so it can vary depending on the environment.

> I always read the term garbage data, and assume that it's just old data already stored there by another process, program... etc.

Worth noting: all modern desktop OSs have memory isolation between processes - your program cannot access the memory of other processes or the kernel (unless you explicitly share it via specialized functionality). The kernel will clear memory before it assigns it to your process, to prevent leaking sensitive data. But you can see old data from your own process, for the reasons described above.

Comment: That response it's just perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking are implementation details that can even vary from run to run. From the perspective of the abstract machine and thus the optimizer they don't matter.

Turning contents of uninitialized memory into almost any type (other than `MaybeUninit`) [is *immediate* undefined behavior](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#initialization-invariant).

```rust
let mem: *u8 = unsafe { alloc(...) };
let x: u8 = unsafe { ptr::read(mem) };


if x != x {
  print!("wtf");
}
```

May or may not print, crash or delete the contents of your harddrive, possibly even *before* reaching that `alloc` call because the optimizer worked backwards and eliminated the entire code block [because it could prove that all execution paths are UB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24527401/1362755).

This may happen due to assumptions the optimizer relies on, i.e. even when the underlying allocator is well-behaved. But real systems may also behave non-deterministically. E.g. theoretically on a freshly booted embedded system memory might be in an uninitialized state that doesn't reliably return 0 or 1. Or on linux `madvise(MADV_FREE)` can cause allocations to return inconsistent results over time until initialized.