Receving wrong bytes over socket. CPP client to Python client
Sending C++ uint32_t to Python client through TCP socket.
I have two functions:

void send_int(uint num)
    {
        
    num = 255; //Assign to 255 for debug purposes 
    num = htonl(num);

    uint8_t* byte_pointer = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&num);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(num); ++i)
    {
      cdbg_print_to_info_channel("%02X ", byte_pointer[i]);
    }

    ssize_t sent = 0;
    const uint8_t* data = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&num);
    while (sent < ssize_t(sizeof(num)))
    {
          ssize_t ret = ::send(clientfd, data + sent, sizeof(num) - sent, 0);
          if (ret < 0)
      {
            // TODO
            break;
          }
        sent += ret;
    }
    cdbg_print_to_info_channel("Sent 255"); 

}

And:
   def receive_int() -> Optional[int]:
            breakpoint()
            int_data = server.recv(4)
            breakpoint()

            print(int_data)

            if len(int_data) < 4:
                print("Error receiving int!")
                return None

            number = struct.unpack('!I', int_data)[0]
            print(number)
            return number

Which are designed to simply send and receive a uint32_t from the CPP client to the Python client.
Running locally, this works perfectly. My CPP side prints the following info:
[17063.126393] (mali-cpu-comman) 00 
[17063.126409] (mali-cpu-comman) 00 
[17063.126416] (mali-cpu-comman) 00 
[17063.126423] (mali-cpu-comman) FF 
[17063.126432] (mali-cpu-comman) Sent 255

in the send_int function, and the python receive_int function prints:
b'\x00\x00\x00\xff'
255

Which are both expected behavior.
The issue arises when I have the cpp client on another machine. The CPP client prints the same info, but the python client prints:
b'\x14\x01\x02\x00'
335610368

The behavior is at least consistent, wherein the "wrong" output will be the same every time, not just a random sequence of bytes.
I suspected this was because of endianness, but I am quite sure it is not as  the endianness is explicit for both instances, but I could be wrong somehow.
Could anyone have any idea why this might be an issue?
So far I have tried to change the endianness of the packets I send through CPP client, and how I unpack it on python side. I have attempted to capture the packets and looking at them through Wireshark, but that left me pretty clueless.

Definitely looks like a sign of C++ undefined behavior, but the reason is not jumping out at me.

You should add more logging to the sent function. Does it send the 4 bytes at once? Does it get into the if (ret < 0)?

I used to do a lot of socket programming in C++, across a wide variety of heterogenous platforms with different architectures, endian-ness, and word sizes. I've not done any socket programming with Python (ignoring using Python to stand-up a web server).  I've not run into this kind of problem.

You are converting to Big endian on the send side, are you sure you're converting back to little endian on the receive side?

i believe technically you are only allowed to alias via char but not uint8_t

@Valdez no shuffling of bytes can restore the right number

I am quite sure I am converting the endianness correctly on both sides, as the endianness is consistent when running locally. The output of the bytes on the python side is before I touch the endianness either way, and should the some combinaton of 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 and 0xFF to signifify one byte that is all ones. @Valdez

@MarkRansom Can you think of another approach that would eliminate running into the same problem?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai the alias is not really relevant to the implementation, just there to be able to visualize the bytes I am making when debugging. It is outputting correct bytes for value=255 as well

That byte sequence does not represent 255.  byte_pointer,4 "ÿ\0\0\0" unsigned char[4] 255,0,0,0.

In general do not sent data using raw sockets, but use a serialization library like protobuf or flatbuffer to do all that stuff for you.

@mch I dont reach the ret < 0 condition

you call send with data which aliases num. Why do you think this isnt important ?

you are making assumptions about the correctness without actually looking. You need to add debugging output in the sending loop to see what actually happens

@463035818_is_not_an_ai youre right, my bad. i will look into it

ret could even be -1 and you wouldnt notice

I agree with @463035818_is_not_an_ai, the cast to uint8_t could be your problem with the send call.  Try casting to char instead.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai added a debug print to check if i reach the condition, which i dont. I will check if moving afa from the uint_8 alias will change anything.
when i said it didnt matter earlier i mistakenly thought you refered to printing of the bytes using byte_pointer

the thing is that even if you would only use it for printing it would matter. UB is nasty, UB can timetravel. Don't assume parts of your code work as you expect when other parts are evidently broken.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Not quite sure what UB refers to (;-;)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527401/undefined-behavior-causing-time-travel

O! Didnt know it was abbreviated like that. Those posts got a laugh out of me @463035818_is_not_an_ai

Those reinterpret_casts look dangerous (beyond that always being a huge red flag).

@faliboiii "Not quite sure what UB refers to" - start reading at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub - make sure to also read all the nice articles linked at the end.

Small update.
Looked through the packets being sent through the port using Wireshark. Seems like the data I want to read is passed earlier than the data I do read. The bytes I want are transferred at 0.459260, while the bytes I do receive are transferred at 0.466428

So I'd have to presume that the issue is caused by code you aren't sharing with us... which is why we have [mcve].
