# Is a program well defined before the line that causes undefined behavior?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

Consider this code:

```
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    int i;
    i = i++ + ++i; // UB
}
```

Is this code guaranteed to print "Hello World!"? The last line invokes undefined behavior, but does that invalidate the whole program?

> I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114459/c-what-is-the-earliest-undefined-behavior-can-manifest-itself) but that question is about C++. This is about C.
>
> It's not a dup of [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) since it's C++. The answer may or may not be the same, but this question is about C.

Comment: I think I read somewhere a program with a line that causes undefined behavior is in fact a program with undefined behavior. Depending on the compiler optimizations weird stuff can happen before said line.

Comment: @kabanus: This is about the standard as it seems. Compiler optimisations are beyond the standard. So relevant is the abstract machine which provides sequence points at best. However, apart from such artificial programs the question does not make much sense for production code.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite I meant that the compiler do whatever it likes, but I see your point.

Comment: @melpomene I added [A C specific answer that also covers C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52262732/1708801) so this is now a solid duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the C standard (3.4.3) :

> **undefined behavior**
>
> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data,
>   for which this International Standard imposes no requirements

Followed by :

> NOTE Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable
>   results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the
>   environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or
>   execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).

This means the standard does not impose any guarantees on the behavior of the entire program - including "earlier" operations.

Specific implementations however, might add certain guarantees for certain instances of undefined behavior (consult your compiler documentation eg.). And [in practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46119976/what-could-happen-practically-on-undefined-behavior-in-c), many implementations do behave in the way you describe for the most part. Optimizations tend to make this difficult to guarantee though. Additionally, [compilers sometimes eliminate entire branches if they contain undefined behavior](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/291548/when-did-undefined-behavior-in-c-jump-the-causality-barrier).

Comment: Here are some practical examples of this actually happening: https://blog.regehr.org/archives/232

Comment: @melpomene: A quality implementation suitable for low-level programming on a particular target platform should allow for the possibility of a volatile access triggering any action that such an access could produce on that platform.  If an implementation will never be used for low-level programming on a platform that defines the behavior of a particular volatile access as e.g. triggering a signal, then optimizing an unchecked divide across a volatile access would be appropriate.  Such an assumption seems dodgy on implementations that claim to be suitable for use with for arbitrary platforms.